# nginx разные error_page по условию

Tags: nginx

На сервере есть список, использующий возможности geo ip для присваивания избранным ip адресам цифрового идентификатора и последующей фильтрации по нему:

```
geo $ip_range {
    default    0;
    a.b.c.d    1;
    e.f.g.h    2;
}
```

в секции `server` размещена проверка:

```
if ($ip_range = 1) {
    return 404;
}
```

Клиенту с адресом отдается код 404 и стандартный текст "Not found".

Я хочу отдавать разные страницы 404 в зависимости от значения `$ip_range`. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Comment: @andreymal я в курсе, как прописать error_page, а как их сделать разными по условию?

Comment: Поместить внурь if же, не? Или это не работает?

Comment: @andreymal "Not allowed here"

Comment: А если всё это вместе поместить в какой-нибудь location?

Comment: В общем в лоб видимо бесполезно. 'return' подразумевает обрыв логики и возврат кода. До обработки error_page. т.е. если надо сменить сообщение об ошибке, то из `if` надо сделать `rewrite` в какой-то `location`, где установить `error_page`, сделать `try_files` несуществующего файла и только тогда вернется кастомное сообщение 404